# How to query a big list efficiently

Tags: vb.net, winforms

What is the best approach to searching through a big custom list? Say for example I have the following list...

```
Dim BigList As New List(Of Button)
For i As Integer = 0 To 99999
    Dim Btn As New Button With {.Text = "Button Number: " & i}
    BigList.Add(Btn)
Next
```

Now to be able to find a specific button in my BigList, I would do...

```
Dim BtnX As Button
BtnX = BigList.Find(Function(p) p.Text = "Button Number: 25784")
```

Since my list of button contains 99,999 buttons, potentially more, how would this affect performance? What's a better and faster way to search through my list, if I know exactly the .Text property of the button before I even search?

Comment: You literally can't make that many window handles.  Why would you need that many controls?  Yes, this affects your performance.  The fewer the controls, the better.

Comment: At worst, you are getting O(n) performance for search as it would just be linear, but you have larger issues in that you cannot make 100,000 controls.

Comment: It's just an example I'm using. My actual list is type of String.

Comment: @TEK, I'm not creating controls, it's just an example of a big list. My big list is actually going to be a string

Comment: @TheNewbie That's a big difference from `Control` to `String`. Perhaps update the question :-)

Comment: If it's a list of strings, why did you feed us a list of controls?

Comment: Because the list I'm working with isn't a regular list, it's a custom class. It contains both controls and strings and such so I just use a Button as an example of a big list

Comment: Well, no, don't do that.  Keep your controls to a minimum.  You are asking an XY question, so we don't know what you are really needing help with.

Comment: I did some testing and it's actually not that slow to search through a list of 99,999. For my need I don't think I will go above 100K items in the list so I think it should be fine.

Comment: Where are you planning to show those Buttons? Maybe, it'll turn out that you actually created just one Button. Or it'll turn out that you don't need a Button for each class instance at all. You could talk about your real use case (i.e, how the Buttons should be used), otherwise it looks like an X,Y problem.

Comment: I don't plan on showing the button. The button is just 1 example of a big list. I'm just asking what IF I have a list of 99,999 items, what is the fastest way of searching through it

Comment: You said: *(...) it's a custom class. It contains both controls and strings (...)*.

Comment: First you say List(Of Button), then List(Of String) and then List(Of MyClass) Which is it? If the latter please provide a sketch of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **using a list of 99999 buttons is a bad idea** -  you have a limit of controls for the entire session of the application. 
every control is a `GDI Object`, if you pass it something is wrong with the architecture of your application and an exception will be thrown.
 instead of using `controls` use [System.Drawing.Graphics class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics?view=netframework-4.7.2) when you can, in order save resources.

from MSDN ([GDI Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/gdi-objects)
):

> There is a theoretical limit of 65,536 GDI handles per session.
>   However, the maximum number of GDI handles that can be opened per
>   session is usually lower, since it is affected by available memory.

**Second**, for your question, you can use `FirstOrDefault()` LINQ extension method:

```
 Dim btn As Button = BigList.FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.Text = "Button Number: 25784")
```

also, if you will use a `HashSet<T>` or an `Array` you will have a better performance compared to `List<T>`

Another approach, is using SortedDictionary -`SortedDictionary (Of Int16, Button)`
and then using a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find your button using the key (of int16) in your dictionary, binary search is faster than LINQ.